# Python Django ImportError: No module named website

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

I am running a sample site on Django 1.5.1 but I am getting ImportError while creating Django app named "website". Here is my Application Heirarchy.

```
TrackLeech
  -- __init__.py
  -- manage.py
  TrackLeech
    -- __init__.py
    -- setting.py
    -- urls.py
    -- wsgi.py
  website
    -- __init__.py
    -- models.py
    -- tests.py
    -- views.py
    templates
      -- index.html
```

Now when I run the command, the server starts well at port 8000 but the localhost:8000 page shows ImportError

`$ python manage.py runserver`

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
July 24, 2013 - 13:29:03
Django version 1.5.1, using settings 'TrackLeech.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-              packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 103, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 321, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 223, in resolve
    return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 230, in callback
    self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 29, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 101, in get_callable
    not module_has_submodule(import_module(parentmod), submod)):
  File "/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named website
```

I am unable to figure that this is the error in the new Django version 1.5.1 or I am making modules the different way or Should I reinstall the Django or  should I use some other Django version. Please suggest me Do I need to change the Django I am using ?

Comment: is website in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: yes I have listed my django app in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: did you follow the right documentation to start your django project? cause it changes a lot from 1 version to another.

Comment: I have watched this screencast on net.tuts http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-from-scratch-creating-a-dynamic-website/ 

and they have used Django 1.3 , Has Django changed this more from Django 1.3 to 1.5

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure you create the app at the basic way: python manage.py startapp website and set the name of the apps in the settings INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was also facing same issue with "login" name.

my app name was "login" and have feature.py in the same.

when i try to import feature using

```
 from login import feature
```

IDE was not showing any issues. intellisense was working fine.

but when i tried to runserver it thrown ImportError: No module named feature.
and as soon as i changed login to extended_login it worked.

So i think some Keywords are not acceptable as app names. You try changing your app name.