# Django Import Error Installed_Apps

Tags: python, django

This is a pretty stupid question and I am sure it will have an equally trivial answer, but I can't seem to figure it out. I get the following error when I run `python manage.py collectstatic`:

```
ImportError: No module named apps.scores
```

How do I properly import the apps.scores app?

The relevant directory tree

```
.
├── manage.py
├── website
│   ├── apps
│   │   └── scores 
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── __init__.pyc
│   │       ├── models.py
│   │       ├── models.pyc
│   │       ├── static
│   │       ├── templates
│   │       ├── tests.py
│   │       ├── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc 
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── views.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── static_collected
```

And the relevant portion of my `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'website.apps.scores',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

Comment: What is your project name?

Comment: I used "website" for this test.

Comment: Does `apps` have an `__init__.py`?

Comment: @Matthias It didn't. After `touch`ing the __init__.py it worked. Thanks

Comment: I have answered same question [here][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843361/python-django-importerror-no-module-named-website/22632216#22632216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
'apps.scores',
```

instead of

```
'website.apps.scores',
```

**Update:** Add an empty file named `__init__.py` in the `apps` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Project directory structure is wrong.

Please follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

from the main project directory when you run `python manage.py startapp scores`

it will list score project in the same directory where `manage.py` is.

to resolve this

In your installed app, try using `scores`

Answer (score 0):

Your **apps** folder is missing an `__init__.py` file to let django recognize it as a module.